# PowerPoint: print slides - enlarge their size

Tags: printing, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

In [PowerPoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_PowerPoint) (2007), it is possible to print multiple slides on a paper as a handout. However, there is quite a lot of whitespace in between them and around them.

Is there another way to enlarge the slides (I'm using the "6 per page" option)? And I don't mean "Adjust to paper size" (or whatever that's called in English), because the difference is just minimal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, the slides on standard handout prints have a lot of blank spaces between them. In order to print the handouts without spaces and just with black lines between slides, you need to head for the `Printer Preferences` and find out if your printer has an option to print `2x2`, `2x3` or `3x3` pages per page. We have a Xerox printer at the company, and it lets us print multiple Powerpoint slides in one page without spaces between them by this way.

Comment: So true. I should have had that idea myself ;) Thanks a ton.

Comment: Nice to help you. You're welcome.